# Dynamiclist is not working

Tags: php

Hello im new to php but i cant make this dynamiclist to work here is the code..

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    include "DocumentSystem/scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$documentCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($documentCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $document_name = $row["document_name"];
             $full_document = $row["full_document"];
             $dynamicList .= '<div id="slidepic">
    <img src="images/document_images/'.$id.'.jpg" width="550" height="350" />
    <div id="slideshow">
    <h1> <a href="document.php?id='.$id.'">'.$document_name.'</a></h1>
    <br />
    <p1><a href="document.php?id='.$id.'">'.$full_document.'</a></p1>
    </div>
</div>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "We have no documents listed in the database";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

It is getting the correct id from the url but the query isnt working for me
thx for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
to usr `mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)`or `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)` instead of `mysql_fetch_array($sql)`
By default mysql_fetch_array return non associative array.

**Pay attention:**

1. Do not `SELECT * FROM table_name`. It's better for performance to use `SELECT column1, colum2 FROM table_name`
2. Mysql module is deprecated. It's better to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) [mysql module page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) [MySQL API comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: It worked by writing "SELECT * FROM documents ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2" i mainly had issues with the tables but when i tried it with divs it started working. Thx for the suggestions il try them at another sql problem i have atm and see if it will work that way. SO i sholdnt use SELECT *??. But i want to get all columns from the mysql...   how i should write it then..?

Answer (score 1):

Please use you have get the query result

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("your_database_name", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo = $row["id"];
  echo = $row["document_name"];
  echo = $row["full_document"];
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```